# unable to compile and run a java program with multiple source files on the command line

Tags: java, command-line, dependencies, classpath, javac

I am trying to compile and run a java program that has 3 source files, and I am not able to get it to run.

I have a folder with 3 java source files, `Tester.java`, `CommandHandler.java`, and `DualList.java`. `Tester.java` contains the main function, and depends on `CommandHandler.java`, which depends on `DualList.java`

I tried to compile the program with `javac Tester.java CommandHandler.java DualList.java`. It created the three class files, but when I try to run the program with `java -cp . Tester` I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Tester
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cmsc420_s22/Tester (wrong name: Tester)
```

I can see that the class file is there, and I got no errors during compilation, so I'm not sure what is going on. I think it might be a problem with my java installation or my configuration. I'm doing this on a kali linux WSL distribution. I haven't changed anything about my installation, and I set my classpath to the current folder so I'm not sure what's wrong

Thanks

Comment: What's the package declaration (in the source files)?  It would be helpful to have a [mcve]

Comment: sorry, I'm not super familiar with java. I got these files from a school project and they were designed to be run in eclipse. They all have `package cmsc420_s22;` as the first line. The package name is also the name of the folder that they're in

Comment: So, assuming, in the terminal, you'r in the `cmsc420_s22` directory, type `cd ..` and then use `java cmsc420_s22.Tester`

Comment: that worked! thanks!

Comment: If you wanna make an answer I'll accept it